# Unzipping a .nii.gz file in python

Tags: python, nibabel

I am using the nibabel package to load an image with 7 parcellations in it.  It is a .nii.gz file and when I try to load it with nibable.load('image_file') I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-8-ef77bd97a272>", line 1
    7net_Buckner_img=nib.load(r'Buckner2011_7Networks_MNI152_FreeSurferConformed1mm_TightMask.nii.gz')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I downloaded the file from here: http://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/CerebellumParcellation_Buckner2011

How can I load this file in nibabel and view it?

Comment: `7net_Buckner_img` is invalid.

Comment: variable can't start at number - remove `7` in name of variable.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you very much,  Pls post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by user above variable can't start at number - remove 7 in name of variable.